# Rich Text Box VB.NET Line By Line Stop and auto?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have this code:

```
    If RotateCount = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count Then
    RotateCount = 0
    End If
    TextBox2.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(RotateCount)
    RotateCount += 1
```

The Question is... How do i get it to STOP after it reads the last line and not keep repeating?
Also, is there a way to automate it so I dont have to keep hitting the button to go to next one?

(for those who need to know this is for an automated Twitter poster for a Cryptocurrency Tipping Bot)

Answer (score 0):

It wont stop because you re-assign `RotateCount = 0` when `RotateCount = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count` it can be avoided by using

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RotateCount = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(RotateCount)
    RotateCount += 1
End Sub
```

If you want to do it automatically means you need to call a time delay between read using a `timer`. you can achieve this by placing a `timer` control from the tool box and then set its interval to `5000`(5sec) and enable it on button click. then the code will be

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If RotateCount = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(RotateCount)
    RotateCount += 1
End Sub
```